# Invalid CORS Request : 403 Forbidden Error Angular

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to make a GET Request in angular using httpClient and i am getting 403 forbidden error.

Steps : 
1. I am using complete URL like "http://myrestapi.aws.net"

**this.httpClient.get(URL);**

When i use this way, i am able to hit the API but i get 403 forbidden error in console "Invalid CORS request"

To overcome CORS issue i installed chrome extension and allowed CORS. But still i am facing same 403 issue.

Can someone provide any input here what i am doing wrong here. Using CORS extension is not ideal solution but this is temporary thing so just using Chrome extension to unblock myself.

Comment: Give more details about your backend implementation please. which aws service, which dev platform. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should enable `CORS` policy on the backend side, not frontend.

Your backend must authorize one or multiple domains to connect to, like a whitelist.

Check your backend solution documentation, and add (whitelist) your frontend hosting domain.

Comment: when i hit this URL directly on the browser i am getting the response. This is happening only when i hit it from angular.

Comment: Presumably because the angular app is running on a different origin. Thierry is correct, you need to configure CORS on your API.

Comment: @meagar, Thank you. Agree but API implementation is not on my side. I am just using an API provided by some other application.  Does CORS chrome extension purpose is to enable cors for this kind of situations.


I also tried creating proxy.conf.json  and adding it in package.json. I face same issue there too.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution for my issue.
I used proxy.conf.json in angular and used the option pathRewrite option.

For pathRewrite documentation referred here. https://angular.io/guide/build